# Downloading file using aws sdk for Nodejs not giving most recent file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

**Summary**

I have a json file that gets updated nightly from an automated testing service. I use this json file to update a UI to show the most recent addition. I am downloading it using nodejs and the aws-sdk.

**The problem**

The file is updated. I have downloaded it and checked it myself. Downloading it programatically using the aws-sdk does not show the updated file however. It's still feeding me an outdated file.

**Code**

Code is fairly simple:

```
 var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params ={
            Bucket: 'vs2020',
            Key: 'nightly/UT Results/UTR.json',
        };
        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
        var response = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.Body)
        var json = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(response)
}
```

I've tried updating the meta data as found through other stack overflow posts, but to no avail.

For example i set `cache-control` to `max-age 0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate`

Thinking this may be wrong syntax, i also set `cache-control` to `max-age = 0`

Neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out S3 keeps a cache of the files and doesn't update it after a certain amount of time. You have to set a metadata field as follows:

`cache-control` : `max-age=0`